# Getting a UIImageView's real rectangle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Greeting All,

I am having trouble to get the rectangle of a UIImageView.
Here is view hierarchy.

```
| MainView
|- DummyView (which applied CABasicAnimation rotation)
|-- ImageView (Desired frame to be get)
```

Since the ImageView is added to a rotating DummyView, is that possible to get the real position of ImageView?

```
- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect toView:(nullable UIView *)view;
- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect fromView:(nullable UIView *)view;
```

ConvertRect is not working in my case.
Please help.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Real position of imageview in what context ?

Comment: `convertRect` must  work in case of coordinates coversion